# Youtube API V3 Searching for a text and getting specific details like Id, views and Snippet image url

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get specific items of Youtube video including Id, snippet.thumbnails.(key).url, statistics.viewCount

I can query for specific to Id by mentioning that in the fields, but not sure how to add additional fields I am interested in there. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

```
                string youtubeApiKey = DataConstants.YoutubeApiKey;
                YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = youtubeApiKey,
                    ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
                });

                var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
                searchListRequest.Q = searchText;
                searchListRequest.MaxResults = 1; // 5
                searchListRequest.Type = "video";
                searchListRequest.VideoSyndicated = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoSyndicatedEnum.True__;
                searchListRequest.VideoEmbeddable = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoEmbeddableEnum.True__;

                // *** Here I need to mention the additional fields *** 
                searchListRequest.Fields = "items(id)";
                // items(id, statistics.viewCount) doesn't work                     


                var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
                {
                        if (searchResult.Id.Kind == "youtube#video")
                        {
                            return searchResult.Id.VideoId;
                        }
                        return null;
                 }
                }
```

searchListRequest.Fields = "items(id)" works but adding additional fields won't work: items(id, statistics.viewCount).

Any idea how to pass these fields correctly

Edit: As mentioned by IkarosKun, search api doesn't support parts for statistics.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method which you use is [searchListRequest](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters), as the docs says, search api only retun the `snippet` part data, If you want to get `statistics` part data, you can just get video data by video id you have get.